# Python: can't merge sort two sorted lists in O(n) starting biggest first

Tags: python, sorting

I have this code:

```
def msort(l1,l2):   

    new=[]
    x=0
    for item in l1:
        if l1[x]>l2[x]:
            new.append(l1[x])
            l1.remove(l1[x])
        elif l2[x]>l1[x]:
            new.append(l2[x])
            l2.remove(l2[x])
        else:
            new.append(l1[x])
            new.append(l2[x])
            l1.remove(l1[x])
            l2.remove(l2[x])
        x+=1
    print(new)
```

and i want it to print this:

```
>>> ssort([9,5,3,2,1],[6,5,4,1])
    [9,6,5,5,4,3,2,1,1]
```

but i get this as my output:

```
[9, 5, 2]
```

why is that? how can i fix it? Im not allowed to use any functions that sort, and it has to be O(n). Im trying to look at the the first 2 items in the list, append the bigger one, get rid of it, then do that again until the list is empty, but it does not seem to be working. The lists are already sorted starting with the biggest number going down.

thanks.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: You can't modify the array you are iterating over (or rather, you can, but you won't get the expected results).

Comment: ok. how would i fix mine? make another copy of each list?

Comment: Consider using two separate index variables for your two source lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not keeping 'x' in sync with the positions in the two lists.
Which suggests that, with this code, you need two indices, one for each list.

A good way to understand why your code isn't working is to grab a deck
of cards, create two sorted mini-decks of, say, 10 cards, and walk 
through your algorithm.  The old and new decks cover `l1`, `l2`, and `new`,
so you'll need pencil and paper to track the value of the other variables,
in this case `x`. You'll quickly see the problem.